# Installing dot net 1.x on Windows 2012

Tags: windows, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying unsuccessfully to install the "Windows Hosting Bundle" used by a legacy web application with dot net core 1.0.x on one of our server running Microsoft Windows 2012 R2 Standard.

I am using the installer found at this link here:

> https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/1.0

The installer completes without any errors and I noticed that the bundle goes into the local folder:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App

[image]

When I run the command "dotnet --list-runtimes" from the prompt, I don't see the runtime listed in the output (and the web application hosted on IIS fail to start).
I am assuming it is not "registered" correctly or?

[image]

Thank you all

Comment: What bitness are you going to support, 32 bit or 64 bit? Go to Control Panel and uninstall the SDK/runtime of unneeded bitness and then things will go back to normal. You cannot mix bitness as that leads to issues like this.

Comment: Thank you @Lex Li, I am targeting 64 bits, I have uninstalled the 32bit versions and now I can see the "Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.x" version listed on the output of "dotnet --list-runtimes". I miss now the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 1.x", do you know where I can download the ASP net core 1.x bundle for 64 bit?

Comment: I don't think in 1.0 there was such a thing. Just deploy the web app and check it out if anything is wrong. Don't expect 1.0 to be the same as the later releases, and so much was missing back then.

Comment: Thank you @Lex Li, I was able to install dot net core 1.0, the web application doesn't still run, I guess will need to open a different issue on that. Thank you